# MySQL Trigger: INSERT table1, UPDATE table2

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I'm wanting to set a trigger as so:

```
TRIGGER `increment_topic_replies_on_insert`
BEFORE INSERT ON  `forum replies` FOR EACH ROW

INSERT INTO `users votes`
SET userid = NEW.userid
    replyid = NEW.replyid,
    forumtopicid = NEW.forumtopicid;

UPDATE `forum topics` ft
SET replies = replies +1
WHERE NEW.forumtopicid = ft.id;
```

So after it INSERTS into `users votes`, it'll update a row in `forum topics`. Should I be using two separate triggers to achieve this?

My current trigger keeps throwing the error "You have an error in your SQL syntax".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your INSERT & UPDATE statement syntax is wrong, try this one

```
CREATE TRIGGER `increment_topic_replies_on_insert` BEFORE INSERT ON `forum replies`
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO `users votes` (userid,replyid,forumtopicid)
    VALUES (NEW.userid, NEW.replyid, NEW.forumtopicid);

    UPDATE `forum topics` ft
      SET ft.replies = replies + 1
    WHERE ft.id = NEW.forumtopicid;
  END;
```